# Calling Python from PHP using shell_exec() in XAMPP

Tags: python, php, xampp, shell-exec

I'm trying to make this work on XAMPP. It works fine on a Linux server/virtual machine.
I need to send an associative array to a python script, and I do it with:

```
<?php
   echo "Test simple call/answer process<br>";
   $age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
   $param = base64_encode(json_encode($age));
   $command = escapeshellcmd('python python_array_answer.py $param');
   $output = shell_exec($command);

   $obj = json_decode($output);
   print_r($obj);
?>
```

The Python script is:

```
#! /Users/.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe
import sys
import json
import base64

hotel_data = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
print(json.dumps(hotel_data))
```

I get a NULL array back, with this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_array_answer.py", line 6, in <module>
    hotel_data = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
  File "C:\Users\mghiglia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (5) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
Any ideas? thank.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of the code is okay, you're using single quotes in this line

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python python_array_answer.py $param');
```

where you should either use double quotes, so php known to replace $param with the value of variable $param, or concatenate the two like this...

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python python_array_answer.py '.$param);
```